# pcap format nor in pcapng format error on Wire shark when clicked on capture on EVE-NG node

Tags: wireshark

Could some one please help to reslove the error quoted below?

> Data written to the pipe is neither in a supported pcap format nor in pcapng format.

This is generated when clicked on capture on EVE-NG node. The error is generated on Latest version of Putty and Wireshark.

Comment: Could you provide more context?  I'm not familiar with EVE-NG or how you're attempting to feed packets to Wireshark.